# Manually added WebResource.axd - Any security implications?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, webresource.axd

I added WebResource.axd (empty file) manually in production environment (IIS7 and Windows Server 2008) after chrome and firefox was giving error 404 for WebResource.axd. And now it is working fine, even with parameters. I am not sure why ASP.NET generating this script in final render result (no problem with VS2008), but now it is working. I want to know, is there any security implications other than what normally associated with WebResource.axd as it is in root directory?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue recently, after a code change WebResource.axd stopped working for my site. Basically, it exposes dynamic resources over http. For a longer explanation visit:

[Just where is webresource.axd?](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/10/28/just-where-is-webresource-axd.aspx)

Typically, what happens is that one of the dynamic resources being requested has failed, but the resource name is encrypted. This blog post will help you decrypt the name, use it and the query string of your failing `webresource.axd?___` request to figure out where the error is coming from.

[Telerik webresource troubleshooting](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/07-03-27/debugging-asp-net-2-0-web-resources-decrypting-the-url-and-getting-the-resource-name.aspx)

Comment: thanks, but I am interested in security implications, after adding WebResource.axd (empty file) manually.